# Incorrect CPU temp on AMD A10-7850 APU (Kaveri) on Ubuntu Linux 3.16 kernel

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu, temperature

My machine has an AMD A10-7850K APU which runs very nicely.

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 when it was released, however it launched with the 3.13 kernel which did not have official support for Kaveri APUs. In particular, the CPU temperature reported was incorrect: It would read around 0 degrees at idle, then maybe 20 under load. 
Regardless, after my upgrade to 14.04.2 I decided to install the utopic HWE, which now sees me running 3.16 kernel, which *does* have support for Kaveri APUs. However, the CPU temperature appears to be the same as before. 0 degrees at idle, 20 under load.

I’m using `lm-sensors` to get the values. Running sensors-detect again actually results in it saying it cannot find any temperature probes at all. Something odd is going on.
Is there a kernel module I have to load to enable Kaveri support to the K10temp implementation?

UPDATED:

Here is the solution found.
My motherboard uses the ITE it8620e chipset, which is not yet officially supported by the it87 driver. 
To fix this, I added the following file:

/etc/modprobe.d/lm_sensors.conf

```
options it87 force_id=0x8728
```

Running 'modprobe it87' then gets the correct temperature details operating.

Full credit to this post [http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2201555&p=12916886#post12916886 ] for having this solution, as well as some additional info in the thread for fixing up the sensor names.

Comment: same issue here: A10-7850K and Kubuntu 14.04

Comment: @Troydm , please see my updated post with the solution!

Comment: This solution worked for me with A10-7850K on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had very similar problem with an A8-7600 & ASUS A88XM-PLUS mobo on UBUNTU 14.04.2.

You are right, the 3.16 kernel is a must.
But you also have to load your mobo's Super I/O chip kernel module as well. In my case It is the Nuvoton nct6775 module.
(Got the info from CPU-Z program, mainboard tab, LPCIO field.)
So in my case:

```
>sudo modprobe nct6775
>lsmod | grep nct
nct6775                55272  0
hwmon_vid              12783  1 nct6775
```

You can also load the module @ boot, if you add It to the /etc/modules file.

```
>cat /etc/modules
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
# Parameters can be specified after the module name.

lp
rtc
nct6775
```

And voila:

```
>sensors
k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:         +1.9°C  (high = +70.0°C)
                       (crit = +70.0°C, hyst = +69.0°C)

nct6791-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:                    +0.84 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)
in1:                    +1.01 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in2:                    +3.44 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in3:                    +3.44 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in4:                    +1.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in5:                    +2.04 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in6:                    +0.28 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in7:                    +3.42 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in8:                    +3.30 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in9:                    +0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
in10:                   +0.17 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in11:                   +0.17 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in12:                   +1.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in13:                   +1.01 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in14:                   +0.22 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
fan1:                  1261 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:                  1223 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
SYSTIN:                 +35.0°C  (high =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C) ALARM  sensor = thermistor
CPUTIN:                 +32.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C) sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN0:               +104.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN1:               +103.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN2:               +103.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN3:               +104.0°C    sensor = thermistor
PCH_CHIP_CPU_MAX_TEMP:   +0.0°C  
PCH_CHIP_TEMP:           +0.0°C  
PCH_CPU_TEMP:            +0.0°C  
PCH_MCH_TEMP:            +0.0°C  
intrusion0:            ALARM
intrusion1:            ALARM
beep_enable:           disabled
```

Works like charm since then..

Best Regards,
2D

Comment: Hey! Thanks very much for this answer. While not the _exact_ answer, it very much put me into the right direction. It definitely was a kernel module issue, particularly with the chipset used on my motherboard.

Specifically, my motherboard uses the ITE IT8620e chipset, which isn't yet officially supported by the it87 driver.

I've updated my post above with the exact solution details used.

Comment: `nct6775` is what was needed for an ASRock A88M-G/3.1 with an AMD A10-7890K on the 4.15 kernel, thanks!